# Objectify + JSP: displaying 1:N relationships

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, spring-mvc, objectify

My bean looks like that:

```
@Entity
public class Fattura {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    String numero;

    @Min(value=0)
    Double importo;

    Key<User> utente;

    // gets & sets....
}
```

The "utente" property is the key of another bean I created: a "Fattura" can have only one "User", one "User" can have many "Fattura"s

My Spring MVC controller will manage a request for a list of Fattura and display them in a simple jsp:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/fatture" , method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView leFatture() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("fatture");


        mav.addObject("fatture",fatturaService.listFatture());

        return mav;
    }
```

*the code of the jsp is really simple: only a foreach cycle in a table*

My question is:

**how can I display the "utente"?**

The only thing I have is its key, but I'd like to do something like **${fattura.utente.firstName}** in my JSP, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you would have to manually fetch "utente" in your DAO class. There is no automatic fetching in Objectify like in Twig. In my POJOs I have following fields

```
@Transient private Organization sender;             // Pickup location (for client RPC)
transient private Key<Organization> senderKey;      // Pickup location (for Datastore)
```

I load entity from Datastore and then load manually Organization using senderKey.

In new Objectify4 you'll be able to do what you want like this:

```
class Beastie {
   @Parent
   @Load
   ParentThing parent;

   @Id Long id;

   @Load({"bigGroup", "smallGroup"})
   SomeThing some;

   @Load("bigGroup")
   List<OtherThing> others;

   @Load
   Ref<OtherThing> refToOtherThing;

   Ref<OtherThing> anotherRef;  // this one is never fetched automatically
}
```

**[Here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/DesignObjectify4)** is evolving design document of new version.

**Update at Nov 17, 2011:** This is big news. **[Twig](http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/)** author, John Patterson, joined Objectify project today.

Comment: I suspected something like this... so do I have to keep duplicate property for each key-relationship??? It's not so nice! Do you suggest me to use Twig or JDO/JPA?

Comment: I updated my answer with link to Objectify4 doc. I had exact thoughts month ago, Fabio. I ended up choosing Objectify because my project will work under significant load and I wanted to have clean simple code where I understand everything what's happening. I was considering Twig but it seems project is not supported much lately. As per JPA I like it but because Datastore is not RDBMS GAE's implementation of JPA has number of weird limitations plus it makes a lot of redundant calls to Datastore which cost you real money.

Comment: Great answer! I wonder how the new @Load will fit my "customer-invoices" use case, but I'm sure there will be excellent documentation. I also came to Objectify from scary comments on using JDO with GAE. Do you know if Objectify will be supported for long time (my future project will need some serious reliability)?

Comment: We should probably address this question to Jeff Schnitzer :) But he said he has three existing projects that use Objectify. I don't think he will stop working on it any time soon.

Comment: JFYI, Twig author, John Patterson, joined Objectify project today.

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds annoying that you have to manually fetch the two objects, but it's actually very useful to know that you're doubling your work and time to do this - each "get" call take a while and the second won't start until the first is complete. It a typical NoSQL environment, you shouldn't often need to have two separate entities - is there a reason that you do?

There are only two reasons I can easily think of:

1. The class references another object of the same type - this is the example in the Objectify documentation, where a person has a reference to their spouse, who is also a person.
2. The class that you're embedding the other into ("Fattura" in your case) has masses of data in it that you don't want fetched at the same time as you want to fetch the "User" - and you need the user on it's own more often than you need the "Fattura" and the "User". It would need to be quite a lot of data to be worth the extra datastore call when you DO want the "Fattura".

Comment: I can't understand your answer 100% .... "It a typical NoSQL environment, you shouldn't often need to have two separate entities" ... but I do need to use the datastore like a RDBMS, unfortunately, so all I'm trying to do is a simple, manual "JOIN". How do you code a simple one-to-many relationship in objectify-gae? Think about a basic case like OFFICE(1) => PERSON(MANY)

Comment: "It a typical NoSQL environment, you shouldn't often need to have two separate entities - is there a reason that you do?" can you explain that to me briefly?

Comment: Sorry, I had thought that you were trying to represent a one-to-one relationship, which is not typically needed. If you want to show a one-to-many, it depends on how you're using it what's best. For example you could list all the users that are in the office using a List<User> on the office object. What are your most common uses of this? Are you more often looking for the office that a user belongs to or looking for a list of users in an office?

Comment: Thank you for replying! My answer is... both! Think about "customers" and "invoices":a report with all invoices amounts of "Italian customers" will be as useful as a report with all the invoices of June2011, with related customers! By now I'm doing two separate fetches, a "manual join"... Objectify4 will introduce @Fetch annotation.... let's see!! :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily have to use temporary field for just getting a object.

This works:

```
public User getUtente() {
    Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
    return ofy.get(utenteKey); 
}
```

This will of course do a datastore get() each time the getter is called. You can improve this by using @Cached on your User entity, so they turn into memcache calls after the first call. Memcache is good, but we can do a little better using the session cache:

```
public User getUtente() {
    Objectify ofy = myOfyProvider.get();
    return ofy.get(utenteKey); 
}
```

The key thing here is that you need to provide (through myOfyProvider) an instance of Objectify that is bound to the current request/thread, and that has the session cache enabled. (ie, for any given request, myOfyProvider.get() should return the same instance of Objectify)

In this setup, the exact same instance of User will be returned from the session cache each time the getter is called, and no requests to the datastore/memcache will be made after from the initial load of this Entity.

Comment: I already knew that obviously: but I DON'T want my entity POJO to be bound / coupled to persistence layer!